# A question in Probability, risk of lung illness

Tags: probability

I was reading this book about medicine and I found this paragraph in it

> A person's daily risk of getting lung illness ... is $0.5$ percent. The daily risk of getting a bad lung illness ... plus treatment is $0.05$ percent. So, you are looking at the difference between a $99.5$ percent chance of staying well, and a $99.95$ percent chance of staying well ... But sum it up over a year and it is the difference between an $83$ percent chance of making it through the year healthy, and a $16$ percent chance.

I don't understand how this conclusion was reached. Was some additional data assumed?

Comment: "So, you are looking at the difference between a 99.5 percent chance of staying well, and a 99.5 percent chance of staying well" The second number should be 99.95 (100-0.05).

Comment: O yes. Made the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they just assumed each day is independent.  Without treatment, with $0.5$ percent chance per day, the chance of getting through a year is $.995^{365}=.160$  With treatment, you have $.9995^{365}=.833$.